# Активность окна игры

Tags: unity3d

Тестирую игру по сети клиент+сервер на одном компе. Пытаюсь синхронизировать движение объектов. 
Проблема в том, что когда запускаю два приложения, объекты движутся только в том, чье окно активно.
Есть ли где-то настройка, чтобы приложение было "активно" всегда?

Answer (score 1):

Есть. Она вот тут:
[image: нужная галочка для "незасыпания" сети в фоновом режиме]
Возможно, Вам стоит также освежить [вот эту](https://unity3d.com/ru/learn/tutorials/topics/multiplayer-networking) серию уроков по сетям от unity